# Reversing the chain rule

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm pretty new to calculus, but is there a way to reverse the chain rule so I can take the antiderivative of 1/(x^3+1) without using partial fractions?

Answer (score 2):

Reversing the Chain Rule when finding an antiderivative is *Integration by Substitution*. You will use it during the integration.

But the partial fractions decomposition comes first.

Answer (score 0):

The partial fractions answer is worked out [here](http://calculus-geometry.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Integrate-Cubic-Denominator).

Comment: Actually, reversing the chain rule is more like $u$-substitution.

Comment: Oh I was thinking product rule for some reason.